# Firebase database return null

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I read a Firebase database, the `city` and `town` variables show me to as null. Why?

```
Denemesiralamaisyerleri deneme = new Denemesiralamaisyerleri();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String id = firebaseUser.getUid();
DatabaseReference userdata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(id);

ValueEventListener rdn = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { // Read user info from the database
        deneme = dataSnapshot.getValue(Denemesiralamaisyerleri.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(UserInterfaceBerber.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

userdata.addValueEventListener(rdn);
city = deneme.getCity();
town = deneme.getTown();
ilin.setText(city);
ilcenin.setText(town);
Toast.makeText(UserInterfaceBerber.this, city + " " + town + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My database structure like this:

```
users
igORGoET3gT6i8CV4wvtuN3l08z1
city:
"Antalya"
email:
"ahmetbulur@gmail.com"
namesurname:
"Ahmet bulur"
phonenum:
"05346789445"
town:
"Alanya"
```

Also, for this *toast* message, the "city" and "town" variable show as null. I expect that it shows me "Antalya" + "Alanya" for the toast message:

```
Toast.makeText(UserInterfaceBerber.this, city + " " + town + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Please post screenshot of your database structure and also which values are returning null?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also indicate the line at which you get null. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo now you can look my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the data is loaded from Firebase asynchronous, you should use that data only when the operation completes, and this only inside the `onDataChange()` method, like in the following lines of code:

```
Denemesiralamaisyerleri deneme=new Denemesiralamaisyerleri();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String id=firebaseUser.getUid();
DatabaseReference userdata=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(id);
ValueEventListener rdn=new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {     //read user info from database
        deneme=dataSnapshot.getValue(Denemesiralamaisyerleri.class);
        city=deneme.getCity();
        town=deneme.getTown();
        ilin.setText(city);
        ilcenin.setText(town);
        Toast.makeText(UserInterfaceBerber.this,city+" "+town+" ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(UserInterfaceBerber.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
userdata.addValueEventListener(rdn);
```

For more info, I recommend you see the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.